# Setting max, min and stepSize values in a Chart.js graph

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to specify maximum, minimum and step size values for my `Chart.js` graph.

Can anyone explain to me why the code below produces this graph?

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fibUr.png)

I'm specifically writing:

```
max: 12,
min: 0,
stepSize: 1.0,
```

[according to the documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#step-size) so I have no idea why my settings are being ignored.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

**Code**

```
<canvas id="h-t"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

<script>
    d3.csv('h.csv')
      .then(makeChart);

    function makeChart(hdata) {
        var t = hdata.map(function(d) {return d.t});
        var h = hdata.map(function(d) {return d.h});        
        var chart = new Chart('h-t', {
          type: 'line',
          data: {
            labels: t,
            datasets: [
              {
                data: h,
                backgroundColor: '#2a54a9',
                borderColor: '#2a54a9',
                fill: false,
//              pointRadius: 10,
//              pointHoverRadius: 15,
                showLine: false // no line shown
              }
            ]
          },
          options: {
              scales: {
                  xAxes: [{
                      gridLines: {
                          drawOnChartArea: false,
                          color: "#111111" 
                      },
                      afterFit: function(scale) {
                          scale.height = 80  //<-- set value as you wish 
                      },
                      scaleLabel: {
                          display: true,
                          labelString: 'Tiempo (min)',
                          fontSize: 18,
//                        fontFamily: 'Cabin Sketch',
                          fontColor: '#111111'
                      },
                      ticks: {
                          fontSize: 16,
//                            fontFamily: 'EB Garamond',
                          fontColor: '#111111',
                          max: 12,
                          min: 0,
                          stepSize: 1.0,
                          padding: 10
                      }
                  }],
                  yAxes: [{
                      gridLines: {
                          drawOnChartArea: false,
                          color: "#111111"                        
                      },
                      scaleLabel: {
                          display: true,
                          labelString: 'Altitud (km)',
                          fontSize: 18,
//                            fontFamily: 'Cabin Sketch',
                          fontColor: '#111111'                        
                      },
                      ticks: {
                          beginAtZero: true,
                          fontSize: 16,
//                            fontFamily: 'EB Garamond',
                          fontColor: '#111111',
                          padding: 10,
                          stepSize: 50,                       
                          suggestedMax: 250,
                          suggestedMin: 0
                      }
                  }]
                
              },
              legend: {
                display: false                    
              },              
           }
        });
    }       
</script>
```

**Edit**

Forgot to add the contents of the input file `h.csv`:

```
t,h
0,0
0.266666666666667,0.4
0.433333333333333,1.2
0.6,2.5
0.766666666666667,4.4
0.933333333333333,6.8
1.1,9.6
1.26666666666667,12.8
1.43333333333333,16.9
1.6,22
1.76666666666667,28.3
1.93333333333333,35.7
2.1,44.2
2.26666666666667,53.9
2.43333333333333,64.7
2.6,76.4
2.76666666666667,88.3
2.93333333333333,100
3.1,110
3.26666666666667,121
3.43333333333333,130
3.6,139
3.76666666666667,148
3.93333333333333,156
4.1,163
4.26666666666667,169
4.43333333333333,175
4.6,180
4.76666666666667,184
4.93333333333333,188
5.1,191
5.26666666666667,194
5.43333333333333,196
5.6,198
5.76666666666667,200
5.93333333333333,200
6.1,201
6.26666666666667,201
6.43333333333333,202
6.6,201
6.76666666666667,201
6.93333333333333,201
7.1,200
7.26666666666667,200
7.43333333333333,199
7.6,199
7.76666666666667,198
7.93333333333333,198
8.1,198
8.26666666666667,198
8.43333333333333,198
8.6,197
8.76666666666667,197
8.93333333333333,198
9.1,198
9.26666666666667,198
9.43333333333333,198
9.6,198
9.76666666666667,198
9.93333333333333,199
10.1,199
10.2666666666667,199
10.4333333333333,199
10.6,199
10.7666666666667,199
10.9333333333333,200
11.1,200
11.2666666666667,200
11.4333333333333,200
11.6,200
11.7666666666667,200
11.9333333333333,201
12.1,201
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've built the X axis of the line chart with `labels`, which are categorical and not numeric.

In order to apply a numeric range to the X axis, you need to do two things:

- Set the xAxis `type: "linear"`
- Change `dataset.data` to `{x, y}` coordinates.

In other words, the `data` that you pass to Chart.js has to look like this:

```js
[
  {x: 0, y: 0},
  {x: 0.26, y: 0.4},
  {x: 0.43, y: 1.2},
  ...
]
```

I've modified your example below to show this in action, including the X axis range from 0 to 12.  Here's what it looks like:

[image: Point line graph with axis range]

Here's the modified code.  Note that I just included your data directly instead of using D3:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

const series = [
  [0, 0],
  [0.266666666666667, 0.4],
  [0.433333333333333, 1.2],
  [0.6, 2.5],
  [0.766666666666667, 4.4],
  [0.933333333333333, 6.8],
  [1.1, 9.6],
  [1.26666666666667, 12.8],
  [1.43333333333333, 16.9],
  [1.6, 22],
  [1.76666666666667, 28.3],
  [1.93333333333333, 35.7],
  [2.1, 44.2],
  [2.26666666666667, 53.9],
  [2.43333333333333, 64.7],
  [2.6, 76.4],
  [2.76666666666667, 88.3],
  [2.93333333333333, 100],
  [3.1, 110],
  [3.26666666666667, 121],
  [3.43333333333333, 130],
  [3.6, 139],
  [3.76666666666667, 148],
  [3.93333333333333, 156],
  [4.1, 163],
  [4.26666666666667, 169],
  [4.43333333333333, 175],
  [4.6, 180],
  [4.76666666666667, 184],
  [4.93333333333333, 188],
  [5.1, 191],
  [5.26666666666667, 194],
  [5.43333333333333, 196],
  [5.6, 198],
  [5.76666666666667, 200],
  [5.93333333333333, 200],
  [6.1, 201],
  [6.26666666666667, 201],
  [6.43333333333333, 202],
  [6.6, 201],
  [6.76666666666667, 201],
  [6.93333333333333, 201],
  [7.1, 200],
  [7.26666666666667, 200],
  [7.43333333333333, 199],
  [7.6, 199],
  [7.76666666666667, 198],
  [7.93333333333333, 198],
  [8.1, 198],
  [8.26666666666667, 198],
  [8.43333333333333, 198],
  [8.6, 197],
  [8.76666666666667, 197],
  [8.93333333333333, 198],
  [9.1, 198],
  [9.26666666666667, 198],
  [9.43333333333333, 198],
  [9.6, 198],
  [9.76666666666667, 198],
  [9.93333333333333, 199],
  [10.1, 199],
  [10.2666666666667, 199],
  [10.4333333333333, 199],
  [10.6, 199],
  [10.7666666666667, 199],
  [10.9333333333333, 200],
  [11.1, 200],
  [11.2666666666667, 200],
  [11.4333333333333, 200],
  [11.6, 200],
  [11.7666666666667, 200],
  [11.9333333333333, 201],
  [12.1, 201],
];

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: series.map(datum => ({
        x: datum[0],
        y: datum[1]
      })),
      backgroundColor: '#2a54a9',
      borderColor: '#2a54a9',
      fill: false,
      //              pointRadius: 10,
      //              pointHoverRadius: 15,
      showLine: false // no line shown
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: "linear",
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false,
          color: "#111111"
        },
        afterFit: function(scale) {
          scale.height = 80 //<-- set value as you wish 
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Tiempo (min)',
          fontSize: 18,
          //                        fontFamily: 'Cabin Sketch',
          fontColor: '#111111'
        },
        ticks: {
          fontSize: 16,
          //                            fontFamily: 'EB Garamond',
          fontColor: '#111111',
          max: 12,
          min: 0,
          stepSize: 1.0,
          padding: 10
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false,
          color: "#111111"
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Altitud (km)',
          fontSize: 18,
          //                            fontFamily: 'Cabin Sketch',
          fontColor: '#111111'
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          fontSize: 16,
          //                            fontFamily: 'EB Garamond',
          fontColor: '#111111',
          padding: 10,
          stepSize: 50,
          suggestedMax: 250,
          suggestedMin: 0
        }
      }]

    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow! This is great! I just have two questions before I accept your answer.
1) Did you modify the input by hand?
2) I see you're including `moment.js`. Why is that necessary? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @RAO, 1) I did modify your input by hand so I didn't have to create a separate CSV.  You should be able to achieve the same result using your existing CSV loader.  2) The moment.js include is not necessary, just part of my Chart.js boilerplate.  I've removed it from the post :)

Comment: You deserve more than just an accepted answer and an upvote. I’m afraid all I can give is my thanks right now 

Comment: Very kind of you!  I am glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Excellent answer - congrats.

For those interested, here code adapted to work with latest `chart.js` version **v3.2.1**

(chart.js **v3.xx** is **not backwards compatible** with **v2.xx**)

instead of **v2.9.3**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"></script>
```

now **v3.x**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
```

(gets you the latest version of chart.js (now at v3.2.1)

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

const series = [
  [0, 0],
  [0.266666666666667, 0.4],
  [0.433333333333333, 1.2],
  [0.6, 2.5],
  [0.766666666666667, 4.4],
  [0.933333333333333, 6.8],
  [1.1, 9.6],
  [1.26666666666667, 12.8],
  [1.43333333333333, 16.9],
  [1.6, 22],
  [1.76666666666667, 28.3],
  [1.93333333333333, 35.7],
  [2.1, 44.2],
  [2.26666666666667, 53.9],
  [2.43333333333333, 64.7],
  [2.6, 76.4],
  [2.76666666666667, 88.3],
  [2.93333333333333, 100],
  [3.1, 110],
  [3.26666666666667, 121],
  [3.43333333333333, 130],
  [3.6, 139],
  [3.76666666666667, 148],
  [3.93333333333333, 156],
  [4.1, 163],
  [4.26666666666667, 169],
  [4.43333333333333, 175],
  [4.6, 180],
  [4.76666666666667, 184],
  [4.93333333333333, 188],
  [5.1, 191],
  [5.26666666666667, 194],
  [5.43333333333333, 196],
  [5.6, 198],
  [5.76666666666667, 200],
  [5.93333333333333, 200],
  [6.1, 201],
  [6.26666666666667, 201],
  [6.43333333333333, 202],
  [6.6, 201],
  [6.76666666666667, 201],
  [6.93333333333333, 201],
  [7.1, 200],
  [7.26666666666667, 200],
  [7.43333333333333, 199],
  [7.6, 199],
  [7.76666666666667, 198],
  [7.93333333333333, 198],
  [8.1, 198],
  [8.26666666666667, 198],
  [8.43333333333333, 198],
  [8.6, 197],
  [8.76666666666667, 197],
  [8.93333333333333, 198],
  [9.1, 198],
  [9.26666666666667, 198],
  [9.43333333333333, 198],
  [9.6, 198],
  [9.76666666666667, 198],
  [9.93333333333333, 199],
  [10.1, 199],
  [10.2666666666667, 199],
  [10.4333333333333, 199],
  [10.6, 199],
  [10.7666666666667, 199],
  [10.9333333333333, 200],
  [11.1, 200],
  [11.2666666666667, 200],
  [11.4333333333333, 200],
  [11.6, 200],
  [11.7666666666667, 200],
  [11.9333333333333, 201],
  [12.1, 201],
];

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: series.map(datum => ({
        x: datum[0],
        y: datum[1]
      })),
      backgroundColor: '#2a54a9',
      borderColor: '#2a54a9',
      fill: false,
      showLine: false
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {   // as of v3.x now object instead of array, 'x: {' instead of 'xAxis: [{'
        type: "linear",
        max: 12,     // as of v3.x now here
        min: 0,      // as of v3.x now here
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false,
          color: "#111111"
        },
        afterFit: function(scale) {
          scale.height = 80
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Tiempo (min)',
          fontSize: 18,
          fontColor: '#111111'
        },
        ticks: {
          fontSize: 16,
          fontColor: '#111111',
          //max: 12,  // as of v3.x not here anymore
          //min: 0,   // as of v3.x not here anymore
          stepSize: 1.0,
          padding: 10
        }
      },
      y: {   // as of v3.x now object instead of array, 'y: {' instead of 'yAxis: [{'
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false,
          color: "#111111"
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Altitud (km)',
          fontSize: 18,
          fontColor: '#111111'
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          fontSize: 16,
          fontColor: '#111111',
          padding: 10,
          stepSize: 50,
          suggestedMax: 250,
          suggestedMin: 0
        }
      }
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
  }
});

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```